# RFC3339 format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, rfc3339

I store a time as VARCHAR(30) as we can see it below:

[image]

I know it is far from best practices.. there is some way to convert such a string into PostgreSQL's time ?

Comment: Just use PostgreSQL TIMESTAMP, that will accept this format. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT

Comment: How to use from it in JPA/Hibernate ?

Comment: Use an AttributeConverter? That way you can configure whatever retarded time syntax you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply casting can do the trick like:

```
SELECT time::timestamptz FROM table;
```

Proof:

```
SELECT '2016-08-12T15:15:01.100001Z'::timestamptz;
         timestamptz
-------------------------------
2016-08-12 15:15:01.100001+00
```

(1 row)

Comment: You saved me :)